# Сортировка словаря по значению не из этого словаря

Tags: python, словари

Мне нужно отсортировать словарь, в определенном порядке, который в самом словаре не определен.

Я получаю с БД такой вот словарь, и мне нужно его вывести так, чтобы сначала шла еда, а потом остальное.

```
tav = {'Газ': 23.0, 'Отопление': 900.0, 'Школа/Кружки': 450.0, 'ОСББ/УК': 481.0, 'Молочка': 35.0, 'Сладости': 40.0, 'Фрукты и Овощи': 50.0}
```

И вот порядок сортировки. Сначала должны выводиться данные по фруктам, потом по молочке и т.д.

```
cats = ['Фрукты и Овощи', 'Молочка', 'Сладости', 'Газ', 'Отопление']
```

#Перебираю каждый элемент словаря, и если ключ есть в CATS, то я ему добавляю нужный порядковый номер.

```
new_list = []
for i in tav:
    if i in cats:
        a = cats.index(i)
    else: a = 99
    new_list.append((i, tav[i], a)) # И добавляю все это в виде кортежа

#Получается так:
#[('Газ', 23.0, 3), ('Отопление', 900.0, 4), ('Школа/Кружки', 450.0, 99), ('ОСББ/УК', 481.0, 99), ('Молочка', 35.0, 1), ('Сладости', 40.0, 2), ('Фрукты и Овощи', 50.0, 0)]

# Сортирую по нужному значению
new_list = sorted(new_list, key=lambda b: b[2])

#И снова закидываю все в словарь.
final_dict = {}
for tuple in new_list:
    final_dict[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
```

И наконец, получаю то что мне надо.

```
#{'Фрукты и Овощи': 50.0, 'Молочка': 35.0, 'Сладости': 40.0, 'Газ': 23.0, 'Отопление': 900.0, 'ОСББ/УК': 481.0, 'Школа/Кружки': 450.0}
```

Скажите, это совсем говнокод?

Как это сделать проще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вариант похожий на уже предложенный:

```
final_dict = dict(sorted(tav.items(),
                         key=lambda x: cats.index(x[0]) 
                         if x[0] in cats 
                         else float('inf')))
'''
{'Фрукты и Овощи': 50.0,
 'Молочка': 35.0,
 'Сладости': 40.0,
 'Газ': 23.0,
 'Отопление': 900.0,
 'Школа/Кружки': 450.0,
 'ОСББ/УК': 481.0}
```

Comment: Круто, я не знал что можно в фильтр так вставить условие.

Answer (score 4):

можно так:

```
import sys


def myindex(el):
    try:
        return cats.index(el)
    except ValueError:
        return sys.maxsize 


new_dict = dict(sorted(tav.items(), key=lambda x: (myindex(x[0]), x[0]))))

>>> new_dict
{'Фрукты и Овощи': 50.0, 'Молочка': 35.0, 'Сладости': 40.0, 'Газ': 23.0, 'Отопление': 900.0, 'ОСББ/УК': 481.0, 'Школа/Кружки': 450.0}
```

если у вас в списке указан изначально верный порядок, то отсортирует именно по нему.
как видим при сортировке мы указываем два параметра, первый это как раз сортировка, как у вас в списке, второй уже по оставшимся ключам по алфавиту.

далее, для чего нам функция с обработкой исключений. Если ее не будет и будем просто делать сортировку по `key=lambda x: (cats.index(x[0])`, то вылетит ошибка, что отсутствуют значения, поэтому в функции мы присваиваем отсутствующим значениям максимальное число (в вашем случае можно и 99, если вас это устраивает и словарь небольшой)

Comment: А можно `key=lambda x: (cats.index(x[0] if len(cats)<x[0] else sys.maxsize)`

Answer (score 1):

Проще пройтись по категориям, а потом добавить то, что вне категорий

```
final_dict = {}
for cat in cats:
  if cat in tav:
    final_dict[cat] = tav[cat]
for k, v in tav.items():
  if k not in final_dict:
    final_dict[k] = v
```

*// Не уверен, что словарь в python - это ordered map, вероятно порядок ключей ничем не гарантирован, тут нужно мнение знатоков*

Comment: Вроде с python 3.7 порядок ключей гарантируется.